# Running sentence transformers at PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pythonanywhere, sentence-transformers

I am trying to run a HuggingFace model for computing vector embeddings as explained [here](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2) at PythonAnywhere (it worked just fine locally on my laptop under Ubuntu under WSL2).

The installation went fine:

```bash
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```

However, when I run the following code:

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import time

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = ms_now()
    
    def stop(self):
        return ms_now() - self.start

sentences = ["This is an example sentence each sentence is converted"] * 10

timer = Timer()
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
print("Model initialized", timer.stop())
for _ in range(10):
    timer = Timer()
    embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
    print(timer.stop())
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/DrMeir/test/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 95, in __init__
    modules = self._load_sbert_model(model_path)
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 840, in _load_sbert_model
    module = module_class.load(os.path.join(model_path, module_config['path']))
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py", line 137, in load
    return Transformer(model_name_or_path=input_path, **config)
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py", line 29, in __init__
    self._load_model(model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir)
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py", line 49, in _load_model
    self.auto_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, config=config, cache_dir=cache_dir)
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 493, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2903, in from_pretrained
    ) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
  File "/home/DrMeir/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3061, in _load_pretrained_model
    id_tensor = id_tensor_storage(tensor) if tensor.device != torch.device("meta") else id(tensor)
RuntimeError: Expected one of cpu, cuda, xpu, mkldnn, opengl, opencl, ideep, hip, msnpu, xla, vulkan device type at start of device string: meta
```

They have `torch` 1.8.1+cpu at PythonAnywhere. On my laptop, it's 2.0.1.

What is the reason for the error and how can I get this to work?

Comment: What happens when you specify device like; `SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2', device='cpu')`?

Comment: @doneforaiur Same error

Comment: I have never seen a `meta` device. It was added with [this PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/53143). So the problem might be version related?

Comment: @doneforaiur I added the torch versions to the question.

Comment: Oh yeah, they added `meta` in 1.9. Might want to downgrade `sentence_transformers` or `transformers` but I'm not sure it will solve this.

Comment: @doneforaiur Sorry for the stupid question, but is the `torch` package Torch or PyTorch?

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question. It's PyTorch but the package name is `torch`.

Comment: @doneforaiur Downgraded `transformers` to 4.6.0 (which is just before the version 1.9.0 of `torch` was released) and it worked!

Comment: Yes! Shame that hugging face endpoints didn't work tho. :^) Can I add this as an answer? I was looking for versions too but couldn't find it...

Comment: @doneforaiur At PythonAnywhere, my paragraphs take some 2.7 seconds on average. That's 3 times faster than HuggingFace at no additional charge (I already pay for the backend) and saving the network communication costs...

Comment: Since it was related to `transformers` library, could you add `huggingface-transformers` tag too? The edit queue is full and I don't have instant edit priviliges. :^) Also, `torch` tag should be `pytorch`. I'm sure there's an error with huggingface endpoints, nobody will use their services...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `meta` device was added in the PyTorch version 1.9. And the PythonAnywhere comes with PyTorch version 1.8.1.

Downgrading `transformers` library to [4.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/transformers/4.6.0/) which was released in May 12, 2021 (before `torch` 1.9 was released) solved this issue.